# Slow Store Procedure in SQL server only sometimes when check stock

Tags: sql, sql-server, query-optimization

Trying to tune a SP in SQL server but kept on slowing in some time when it is busy, I guess there are many select in the query, is there a way to write this SP in better way which will have more performance is faster, all the table belonging in the SP has indexes in them

```
     [dbo].[sp_StockCheck](
@Code int,
@StockID INT
)
as
Declare @StockQty int
Declare @InventoryQty int


DECLARE Private int 
DECLARE ISPrivate bit


SELECT Private=SUBGROUP_CODE FROM dbo.PostNode With(NoLock)  WHERE CODE = @Code 

SET ISPrivate = CASE WHEN Private IN (9,12,15) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END


IF (ISPrivate =1)
BEGIN
    SELECT 1000 AS RemindedStockQty
END
ELSE
BEGIN

Declare @_sid int=0
select @_sid=StockID from StockCheck With(NoLock) where ID = @StockID

declare @CategoryID int = (select MCS.TypeID from Master_CoverStock MCS With(NoLock) where MCS.ID = @StockID)

Declare @Qty int=0
    select @Qty= isnull(SUM(isnull([Count],0)),0) from StockCheck With(NoLock) where IsActive=1 and StockID=@StockID and Code=@Code 
if((Select 1 from NewCode With(NoLock) where Code= @Code)=1 AND @StockID between 45 and 53 and @Qty > 0)
begin
    SELECT @StockQty=isnull(sum(isnull(StockQty,0)),0) FROM StockDetail With(NoLock)  WHERE Code=@Code 
    AND StockID IN ((SELECT csm.ID FROM StockCheck csm With(NoLock) where IsActive=1 and StockID=@StockID and Code=@Code ))
    AND CategoryID = @CategoryID
    AND Deleted='N'
    
        select @InventoryQty=@Qty
        select (@InventoryQty-@StockQty)RemindedStockQty
    
end
else
    begin
        SELECT @StockQty=isnull(sum(StockQty),0) FROM StockDetail With(NoLock)  WHERE Deleted='N' and Code=@Code and StockID=@StockID
        select @InventoryQty=isnull(sum(Quantity),0) from tblStockInventory With(NoLock) where StockID=@StockID and Code=@Code
        select (@InventoryQty-@StockQty)RemindedStockQty
    end
END
```

Comment: Have you looked at the execution plans when it is slow vs. fast? Have you examined the wait types when the procedure gets slow? Have you checked for blocking (still possible, even with all those NOLOCKs)?

Comment: the query one has 100% cost on cluster index, query two has 100% scan on non cluster index, query three has 100% cost in cluster index and have a nested loop, query four has 96% on clustered indexes and 4% on scalar, query five has a nested loop and 100% index is on cluster indexes, query six has cost 99% on RID lookup(heap) and two nested loop

Comment: % cost is pretty useless, as you can see from your description. :-) [This might be a useful read](https://www.erikdarlingdata.com/how-to-get-answers-to-sql-server-performance-questions/).

Comment: Query plans are essential for performance questions, please upload to https://pastetheplan.com and share the link. Is there any reason you are using `NOLOCK`, it's not a go-faster switch?

Comment: The query looks like it contains a lot of business logic. Business logic should never be part of SQL. I do not know from where the query is executed, but I recommend to split it into multiple queries and do those logic checks (IFs) in your backend.

Comment: Might want to consider breaking this out into multiple procs and use `option recompile` on those simple parameterised queries.

Comment: To troubleshoot query-optimization problems in SPs, start by running the queries one-by-one in SSMS outside the SP. Look at the actual execution plans, which may suggest an index you need. Right-click in a SSMS query window, then select Show Actual Execution Plan, then run the query. The execution plan display sometimes recommends a new index to create.  To help you with your [tag:query-optimization] question, we must see table definitions, index definitions, and the output of EXPLAIN. Please [read this](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/query-optimization/info), then [edit] your question.

Comment: what are the alternative way to write this query instead of select in select, checked the tables the was one table that was using heap 98% and changed it and put a cluster index for that still is slow what would be the alternative to write this query